# How to hide properties of wpf Control in xaml implementation?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created a Control (let's say Control.cs and Control.Generic.xaml for the view).
I would like to create properties in Control in order to bind it in the view.
But, I don't want to see those properties when implementing this control in other views.

For example in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<MyControl PropertyOnlyVisibleInsideControl="I don't want this property visible"/>
```

I must not be able to set this property as it is used in internal (Control.Generic.xaml):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type generics:MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type generics:MyControl}">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding PropertyOnlyVisibleInsideControl}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I tried with a dependency property (Control.cs):

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public string PropertyOnlyVisibleInsideControl
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(PropertyOnlyVisibleInsideControlProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PropertyOnlyVisibleInsideControlProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Or with a simple property (Control.cs):

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public string PropertyOnlyVisibleInsideControl
    {
        get
        {
            return _property;
        }
        set
        {
            _property = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("PropertyOnlyVisibleInsideControl");
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me achieve this?
Thank you :)

Comment: Have you tried making the property `private`? The XAML should have access to it.

Comment: I tried but can't bind to non-public property...